# jquery plugin creation issue

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I have created a plugin with following codes:

```
var myplugin = {
    init: function(options) {
         $.myplugin.settings = $.extend({}, $.myplugin.defaults, options);
    },
    method1: function(par1) {
        .....
    },
    method2: function(par1) {
        .....
    }
};
$.myplugin = function(method){
     if ( myplugin[method] ) {
    return myplugin[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
     } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return myplugin.init.apply(this, arguments);
     } else {
    $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" does not exist in myplugin!');
     }
};
$.myplugin.defaults = {
     option1: 'test',
     option2: '',
     option3: ''
};
$.myplugin.settings = {};
$.myplugin();
```

This works well but the issue is that when I try to set more than 1 option and try to return its values afterwards, it gives empty; setting one option works well. For eg.
If on changing the first combo box value I call this:
    $.myplugin({option1: 'first test'});
it works, but when I try to call another on second combo box it doesn't save the option, instead it reset to empty.

Is there any fix?

Comment: Your plugin isn't written to handle multiple elements, you should probably be using `$.fn.myPlugin` instead of `$.myPlugin`

Comment: actually I don't want to use it as a jquery prototype with elements. I just want to use it as a regular function to perform different actions.

Comment: You can't store `settings` where you are storing it, otherwise every time you use the plugin it will override any settings previously set. They have to be stored somewhere relevant to what they are affecting, usually on an element's data object. `$(element).data("mypluginsettings",settings)`

Comment: Great and helpful reply. I am wonder that if this data object is available for global use if I don't want to use it with any element?

Comment: You would need to store a different settings for each instance of your plugin that you create, and those settings would need to persist in some kind of object that your plugin returns. You would then use that returned object to perform actions with that instance.

Comment: Can you please provide with some example of how to store them persistently in an object? At the moment I am using $.myplugin({option1: 'saved'}) and $.myplugin.settings.option1 to retrieve it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-organize the plugin to use this structure:

```
var methods = {
    settings: {
        foo: "foo",
        bar: "bar"
    },
    init: function(options) {
        this.settings = $.extend({}, this.settings, options);
    },
    method1: function(par1) {
        alert(this.settings.foo);
    },
    method2: function(par1) {
        alert(this.settings.bar);
    }
};

function MyPlugin(options) {
    this.init(options);
    return this;
}
$.extend(MyPlugin.prototype, methods);
$.myPlugin = function(options) {
    return new MyPlugin(options);
}

/* usage */

// without parameters
var obj1 = $.myPlugin();
// with parameters
var obj2 = $.myPlugin({foo: "foobar"});
// each has it's own settings
obj1.method1();
obj2.method1();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ypXdS/

Essentially `$.myPlugin` simply creates and returns a new instance of the MyPlugin class. You could get rid of it completely and use `new myPlugin(options)` in it's place.

Comment: Kevin, thanks a lot for the example I will check it in a while. One last question. In following example: var myplugin = {
    init: function(options) {
         $.myplugin.settings = $.extend({}, $.myplugin.defaults, options);
    },
    method1: function(par1) {
        .....
    },
    method2: function(par1) {
        .....
    }
};
How can I call method1 from method2 and vice versa?

Comment: Using your method, or mine? In mine it would simply be `this.method1()` and `this.method2()`, in yours it would be `$.myplugin.method1()` and `$.myplugin.method2`

Comment: Kevin thanks a lot, it have solved my problem. :) In the meantime can you suggest me a book in which I can learn more in detail about these type of object creation in jquery.